# Livepatch is Stuck?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 for several years now. I recently had cause to do a clean install, and decided to finally upgrade to 18.04. During the install, I enabled Livepatch. (I'm a pretty low-level user, and this machine is is pretty basic: email, internet, LibreOffice, occasionally I'll use Handbrake or Gimp. I'm not exactly taxing the hardware or software. 99.9% of the time, I'm totally fine trusting Ubuntu to take care of itself.)

Anyway, every time I start the computer, I get the notification that Livepatch has installed 19 updates. Always 19 updates. Now, either it's an amazing coincidence that exactly 19 updates come through between every restart, or something is stuck. It doesn't seem to affect usability at all, but I can't help wondering if I'm actually getting all the latest updates, and could *maybe* lead to problems somewhere down the line.

The machine in question is a Lenovo IdeaPad Z570, running Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.2.

Any thoughts? Or is this a non-issue? Thanks!